# Как можно передать значение из .properties в javascript файл?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, properties

Иногда бывает необходимо передать некоторые переменные из properties в javascript файл. Когда js код подключен инлайном, то нет проблем с передачей нужной переменной при помощи thymeleaf. Как можно передать определенную переменную из properties в js файл? Заранее спасибо!

На данный момент у меня есть 2 решения:
1) Создать @ControllerAdvice и добавить @ModelAttribute, а в методе возвращать Map. Вывести его в thymeleaf при помощи th:each. А дальше скриптом получить data атрибут нужного тега.
2) Создать @RestController с методом GET, который при обращении отдает Map. А дальше скрипт делает аякс запрос к урлу и получает нужные параметры.

Comment: Во-первых, Thymeleaf можно настроить на обработку js-файлов. Во-вторых, можно данные вставлять в страницу, а в коде из подключаемых js-файлов эти данные использовать. В-третьих, можно написать дополнительный эндпоинт на бэке, который будет отдавать данные в ответ на запрос с фронта.

Comment: Здравствуйте! В принципе, первый вариант верен для инлайн скриптов. А второй и третий вариант я уже реализовал. Думал, может есть какой-нибудь другой вариант, который давал бы такую возможность. Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодарю всех, кто помог решить данный вопрос.
Для меня подошел следующий вариант:
1) Создал `@ControllerAdvice`, который передавал `@ModelAttribute` во все шаблоны

Простой пример:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerAdvice {
@Value("${base.url}")
  private String baseUrl;
// Получить нужные переменные из properties
  @ModelAttribute("baseUrl")
  public String getBaseUrl() {
    return baseUrl;
  }
}
```

Далее в head вставляется следующий код. (В данном примере использую Thymeleaf)

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    var baseUrl = [[${baseUrl}]];

    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

После чего эта переменная доступна в документе и ее можно спокойно использовать, как в инлайновых скриптах, так и в подключаемых скриптах.

Другие варианты реализации:
Создать контроллер и GET метод, который при обращении к url вернет JSON (Map). А далее скрипт отправляет аякс запрос к урлу и парсит результат.

Другой вариант - если скрипт инлайновый и вы используете шаблонизатор thymeleaf, то можете спокойно использовать переменные в инлайновых скриптах.